# Question without title

Tags: bug, questions

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/273132/revisions is missing the original revision by OP (perhaps it was nuked for containing credentials?).

When editing the question, the title field is empty. When cancelling the edit, the title above the question disappears.

Comment: Yes, the first revision was "destroyed", as it is called. Note another bug: the first revision shows that psubsee2003 asked it and not edited.

Comment: Seems like they should not completely destroy it, but instead empty it, to avoid those artifacts. So there should be a ghost-revision left.